# How do I change the size of the darken on a navbar hover?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to style my navbar and work on its aesthetics but I think I'm missing a trick. The darken which happens on the hover is too big for my liking, but the only size change I can do is an overall padding which doesn't allow fine tuning.

I've spent the last 2 hours looking for a solution and I'm stumped. I bet it's something simple and I'm just not seeing it.

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6%;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  z-index: 2;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  height: 6%;
  border: 1px inset #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class=buttonContainer>
    <div class="homeBorder">
      <a href="#home">Home</a> </div>
    <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the white oval thats appearing arround the anchor?

Comment: Can you clarify what 'size of the darken' means, and what you want your end result to be?

Comment: By darken I mean the effect that happens when you hover over the buttons, which in this case is the oval appearing and the colour changing. Sorry I should've realised I gave no context for the darken. I want to be able to change the distance between the oval border and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code does not show any "darkening" but I hope I still understood your question correctly: You want the background of the navbar links to be of a certain color on hover but the area is too big, especially in height?

You are right, your issue is caused by the 10px-padding that you have set on your link elements. I would recommend you to reduce the padding to maybe 5px to achieve the height you would like to see on hover (same padding for normal and hover, otherwise the links "jump" on hover). You could then wrap all links in an additional div to make universal changes or you could simply work with margins instead. I would also recommend not setting a specific height on the navbar but letting the elements inside determine its height by using padding and margin.

What always helps me when dealing with spacing in CSS, is adding differently colored backgrounds to ALL of the elements involved as to understand their behavior and to test my code.

In case there is a specific reason why you cannot reduce the padding, then please edit your question and make your requirements clearer.

Btw, there is one fatal error in your code:

```html
<div class=buttonContainer>
```

should be:

```html
<div class="buttonContainer">
```

(quotes!!)

...and ideally it should be:

```html
<div class="button-container">
```

as it's not best practise to use camel case in CSS as opposed to JS or other programming languages.

Comment: Thank you! I am setting the height, because the padding in '#navbar a' is causing the banner itself to change in size.
I can't believe I missed that, but I wasn't using that class anyway, I should've removed it before posting. I'm using camel case because i'm unsure how to reference "button-container" is it just ".button-container"?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The correct way to select this class in CSS would be ".button-container". Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Not this specifically, thank you! I'm having trouble overall, I've only been using html and css for about a month now, it has quite the learning curve.

Comment: You’re welcome! It gets better over time, I promise! :) - keep posting your questions to the community on Stack Overflow and if I see it, I’m happy to help you out.